# How remove "localhost:portno" when running an asp.net website under iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis

How remove "localhost:portno" when running an asp.net website under iis?... When i browse my virtual directory i can `http://localhost:120/mine/Forms/Clients.aspx`.....

Answer (score 1):

If your using IIS 7+ you can create a website (or edit its bindings).  In the bindings, add your url that you would like specified. I usually follow {projectName}.{machineName}.{CompanyDomainName}.com.

Then open up notepad, notepad++, ect as admin and open up the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add the following:

127.0.0.1   {url you specified for the binding}

Restart IIS and when you navigate to the binding url, it should open the site.

Example:
Machine Name: Colorado
Domain Name: stackoverflow
Project Name: userDashboard

Binding: UserDashboard.Colorado.StackOverflow.com

Host File:
127.0.0.1     UserDashboard.Colorado.StackOverflow.com

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Configure your virtual directory in Default website in IIS where port = 80 OR set website port = 80.
For port 80 you need not to define port in URL.

To set port, Go to website properties > In website tab > See TCP Port

Comment: Chandru, provide more details. Where do you get object not found error? Are you running anything else on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify port explicitly only when running non-default websites on IIS. 
Deploy you app to default website (or to virtual directory in it). Default website configured to 80 port so you can just type in browser "http://localhost/{virtual_directory}"